# How do I set the x-axis (xaxis) on a Bar Graph in Spotfire with IronPython?

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

I need to change the column used on the x-Axis on a bar chart.
how can I do this in IronPython?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I do it.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent

#"visual" is the name of the parameter found in the "Script Parameter" dialog below the editor which points to the visualization I want to change.
vc = visual.As[VisualContent]()
exp="["+Document.Properties["DocPropertyNameHere"]+"]"
vc.YAxis.Expression =exp
```

Answer (score 1):

change what on the x axis?

```
#change the Range from 0 to 100:
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent, AxisRange
viz= viz1.As[VisualContent]()
viz.XAxis.Range = AxisRange(0,100);
```

For more attributes, see the [API](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/doc_remote/spotfire/6.5.0/api/Index.aspx)

Comment: oops, forgot to leave a comment when I clarified the question.